# Samba, windows domain sharing and management

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I have setup ubuntu-server to take over as the main file server on my domain and successfully managed to get it recognising all the windows AD users and groups using Centrify express, I did try to add it to the local domain and access all the users and groups with Samba but had no luck after multiple attempts.

I am now wondering what the best way to manage the share directory access is, should I use ACL ?

I would like it so that if I have a directory structure for example

```
DIR1
|----SUBDIR1
|----SUBDIR2
|----SUBDIR3
|----SUBDIR4
|----SUBDIR5
|----SUBDIR6
```

Now if I wanted USER1 to only be able to see SUBDIR 1-4 but not 5 and 6 and USER2 to only see 5 and 6 but not 1-4, what would be the best way to achieve this please ?

I know I could share each directory individually but I would prefer to only share the main DIR1 so as not to have multiple shares.

Thank you in advance